# Loop Multi-Contingency using etoolbox

Tags: conditionals, loops, etoolbox

I want to use the `etoolbox` package to manage some loop contingencies over a counting index.  In particular, I'd like to do something different on the first and last times through the loop.

Now I can formulate ways to do that, for example in this MWE.  In the first case, I use a nested `\ifboolexpr` whereas in the second example, I set up an arcane switching system for `toggle`s.  Both of these approaches accomplish the underlying goal...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{index}%
\begin{document}
\def\LAST{10}

\noindent%
\setcounter{index}{0}%
\whileboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\theindex}<{\LAST}}}{%
\stepcounter{index}%
\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\theindex}{=}{1}}}%
  {NOT\\}%
  {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\theindex}{=}{\LAST}}}%
    {NOT\\}%
    {\theindex\\}%
  }%
}

\newtoggle{flag}
\noindent%
\setcounter{index}{0}%
\togglefalse{flag}%
\whileboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\theindex}<{\LAST}}}{%
  \stepcounter{index}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\theindex}{=}{\LAST}}}{%
    \togglefalse{flag}}{}%OFF FOR LAST COLUMN
  \iftoggle{flag}{\theindex\\}{NOT\\}%
  \toggletrue{flag}% ON FOR COLUMNS 2 TO \LAST-1
}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the documentation leads me to believe that I should be able to use a Boolean `and` or `or` to accomplish this contingency with a single `\ifboolexpr`.   And yet, I have been unable to construct such a syntax to do so.  Is there a way, using the `etoolbox` syntax, to perform a single "if" check to determine if this is "the first excursion  OR  the `\LAST` excursion" through the loop, or alternately, if this is "not the first excursion  AND  not the `\LAST` excursion" through the loop?

Comment: And this *is* specific to an iteration over numerals, not random items, right?

Comment: @Werner Yes, the iteration is a simple incremented index from 1 to a maximum value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to combine conditions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcounter{index}%
\begin{document}
\def\LAST{10}

First: \par
\noindent%
\setcounter{index}{0}%
\whileboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\theindex}<{\LAST}}}{%
\stepcounter{index}%
\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\theindex}{=}{1}}}%
  {NOT\ }%
  {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\theindex}{=}{\LAST}}}%
    {NOT}%
    {\theindex\ }%
  }%
}

Second: \par
\newtoggle{flag}
\noindent%
\setcounter{index}{0}%
\togglefalse{flag}%
\whileboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\theindex}<{\LAST}}}{%
  \stepcounter{index}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\theindex}{=}{\LAST}}}{%
    \togglefalse{flag}}{}%OFF FOR LAST COLUMN
  \iftoggle{flag}{\theindex\ }{NOT\ }%
  \toggletrue{flag}% ON FOR COLUMNS 2 TO \LAST-1
}%

Third: \par
\noindent%
\setcounter{index}{0}%
\whileboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{index}}<{\LAST}}}{%
  \stepcounter{index}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumgreater{\value{index}}{1}}%
    and
    test {\ifnumless{\value{index}}{\LAST}}}%
  {\theindex\ }%
  {NOT\ }%
}
\end{document}
```

"First" and "Second" matches your original loops, while "Third" uses an `and` clause to merge two `test`s.

Comment: That's excellent.  For whatever reason, I couldn't get such an approach to work with `\ifnumcomp`, but `\ifnumless` and `\ifnumgreater` do the trick.