# etoolbox for loop over range

Tags: loops, etoolbox, for-loop

Is there a way to run a command on a range of consecutive integers (say, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), specifying only the first and last numbers (11 and 15)? Basically I'm looking for the general LaTeX equivalent of `tikz`'s `\foreach \x in {11,…,15}`.

In the MWE below (using `etoolbox`), `\forcsvlist\mycommand{11,12,13,14,15}` correctly runs `\mycommand` on each of the four inputs, and `\myrange{11}{15}` indeed expands to `11,12,13,14,15`. But putting them together `\forcsvlist\mycommand{\myrange{11}{15}}` doesn't work. I think it comes down to order of expansion, which is way over my head.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, etoolbox}
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{\boxed{#1} }
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand\myrange[2]{
    \defcounter{mycounter}{#1}
    \themycounter%
    \whileboolexpr
        {test {\ifnumless{\themycounter}{#2}}}
        {\stepcounter{mycounter},\themycounter}
    }
\begin{document}
\forcsvlist\mycommand{11,12,13,14,15}
does not equal
\forcsvlist\mycommand{\myrange{11}{15}}
\end{document}
```

I've looked at [Loop Multi-Contingency using etoolbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140372/loop-multi-contingency-using-etoolbox), [Print all elements of a working array created with etoolbox package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184296/print-all-elements-of-a-working-array-created-with-etoolbox-package), and [Remove extra curly braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300865/remove-extra-curly-braces),
but couldn't figure out how to apply them to this situation.

Comment: You are defining and setting counters in your `\myrange`macro -- this can't be expandable. There might be more issues, but I can't check right now

Comment: Similar (?) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360959/31729

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just as easy to loop without any specific package code in this case.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{\boxed{#1} }

\makeatletter
\newcommand\zz[3]{%
 #1{#2}%
 \ifnum#2=\numexpr#3\relax\expandafter\@gobblefour\fi
 \zz#1{\the\numexpr#2+1\relax}{#3}%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\zz\mycommand{11}{15}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you get nested \numexpr which numexperts usually remove by suitable \expandafter ;-) (this may also surprise macro \mycommand if the latter parses in some way its argument and chokes on ten nested \numexpr's)

Comment: @jfbu I wondered about adding more expandafter but thought it would obscure the main point, it's not actually wrong is it?

Comment: nothing wrong ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Optionally providing also the step; the `\int_step_function:nnnN` macro takes as argument the starting point, the step, the final point and finally the one parameter macro to which the current value is passed as argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\mycommand[1]{\fbox{#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\forrange}{mO{1}mm}
 {
  \int_step_function:nnnN { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } #4
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\forrange{11}{15}{\mycommand}

\forrange{11}[4]{27}{\mycommand}

\forrange{15}[-1]{11}{\mycommand}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\newcommand\mycommand[1]{\fbox{#1} }

\newcommand\forrange[4][1]%
    {\xintFor*##1in{\xintSeq[#1]{#2}{#3}}\do{#4{##1}}}

\begin{document}

\forrange{11}{15}{\mycommand}

\forrange[4]{11}{27}{\mycommand}

\forrange[-1]{15}{11}{\mycommand}

\end{document}
```

Now I picked over that abstraction from another authoritative answer. For everyday use you can also use

```
\xintFor #1 in {99, 37, -53, 'zouzou'}\do{ whatever }
```

and replace `#1` by `##1` if inside a macro definition.

[image]